# How to get the index of an element in a vector of variants?

Tags: c++, vector, variant, static-cast

From a `vector<variant<T1,T2>> vec` I have a `T1& elem` that is known to be in `vec`. I want to find the index `i` such that `get<T1>(vec[i])` is `elem`.

But I'm not sure if this is legal:

```
auto const p = static_cast<std::variant<T1,T2> const*>(&elem); // 1
auto const i = static_cast<std::size_t>(p - vec.data()); // 2
```

I'm not sure that the static cast in `// 1` is legal, even if `holds_alternative<T1>(vec[i])` holds.

---

*Edit: From the discussion below this question boils down to: **How do I do line `1` in a standards compliant way?***

Comment: `// 1` is exceedingly bad, because you have no guarantee of how the `variant` is laid out

Comment: @ZuodianHu Yes, I thought as much. I'm looking for the correct way to do this.

Comment: @RSahu Actually, I'm fairly confident that `// 2` is fine (under the assumption that `elem` actually *is* in the vector).

Comment: I retract my previous comment. You said *I have a `T1& elem` that is known to be in `vec`* Under that assumption, (2) will be well behavoed if (1) could be used to get a valid `p`.

Comment: This seems impossible without a `O(N)` search while sticking to the standard, given `variant`'s interface. You can certainly do some funky pointer arithmetic knowing you have to handle some unknown offset into `variant` elements, but at that point why not just make sure the code has an iterator to begin with?